# Compare two date columns and validate if DateA is earlier than DateB

Tags: python

I have two columns with dates(mm/dd/yy). I need to validate if DateColumn_A comes before DateColumn_B.

I used the following code and I got this error "TypeError: must be string, not Series". Please help a beginner.

Code:

```
Column_A = datetime.strptime(df['DateColumn_A'], '%m %d %y')
Column_B = datetime.strptime(df['DateColumn_B'], '%m %d %y')

for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    if row[Column_A] < row[Column_B]
        print (index,row[Column_A])
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: If the columns you are comparing are `datetime64` then how about `df['DateColumn_A'] < df['DateColumn_B']`?

Comment: @Orenshi I will try your incorporating suggestion. Thanks for taking your time to reply to my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare them like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

Column_A = datetime.strptime(df['DateColumn_A'], '%m %d %y').date()
Column_B = datetime.strptime(df['DateColumn_B'], '%m %d %y').date()
diff = Column_A - Column_B
if diff > 0:
    # Column_A is greater than Column_B
else:
    # Column_B is greater than Column_A
```

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on my comment above with an example.

First make sure the date columns you are comparing are actually dates. You can do that using the pandas `to_datetime` function like so:

```
>>> df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='ignore')
>>> df.DateColumnA
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-05-01
Name: DateColumnA, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The below snippet is using boolean indexing. So `df['DateColumnA'] < df['DateColumnB']` returns a series of Trues and Falses. And then `df.loc[df['DateColumnA'] < df['DateColumnB']]` is akin to saying "Give me the subset of the DataFrame where this condition is True"

```
 >>> df
  DateColumnA DateColumnB
0  2018-01-01  2018-02-01
1  2018-05-01  2018-01-01
>>> df['DateColumnA'] < df['DateColumnB']
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
>>> df.loc[df['DateColumnA'] < df['DateColumnB']]
  DateColumnA DateColumnB
0  2018-01-01  2018-02-01
```

Comment: I upvoted this but be careful to pass params as errors='ignore' as it can lead to errors in next step.

Answer (score 1):

The error you report is occuring in the first line of code since strptime can only convert single dates, not a whole series.  Try this instead:

```
df['DateColumn_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateColumn_A'])
df['DateColumn_B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateColumn_B'])
print (df.index[df.DateColumn_A < df.DateColumn_B])
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know why my code was not working. I will be working with a series of dates and your explanation is much appreciated!