# Pandas - Conditional Logic with Date Objects

Tags: python, pandas, date

It seems that despite the fact when I check my pandas columns and it returns a dtype of  `dtype: datetime64[ns]`, I cannot get the two columns below in my code to compare during a conditional statement (Completed Date < Original_Due_Date).Mind, the Completed_Date column was used earlier in the code to compare against a date and it worked there.

The error I get stems from the line 4 lines up from the bottom: copied below

```
finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Original_Due_Date' >= 'Completed_Date'),'On_Time_Units'] = 'Order_Qty'
```

Error:

```
 ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
```

Full code below (cannot post data set because it is private)

```
if day_of_week !=0:
    finaldf['Completed_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Completed_Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
    finaldf['Due_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Due_Date'], format="%m/%d/%y") # making it lower case y made it work
    current_week_flags = (finaldf.Completed_Date >= last_monday) & (finaldf.Completed_Date <= today)
    finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Completed_Date'] >= last_monday) & (finaldf['Completed_Date'] <= today) & (finaldf['Due_Date'] < last_monday), 'Due_Date'] = last_monday
    #appears to be working great as of 4.17
    finaldf = finaldf.merge(origdue, on='Work_Order', how= 'left') #vlookup, puts column on outer right 
    finaldf = finaldf.merge(rcode, on='Work_Order', how= 'left')

    #above was working on 4.17
    test = (finaldf.Due_Date >= last_monday) & (finaldf.Due_Date < today)
    finaldf = finaldf[test]
    #above we filtered for the date range, mind the test is  boolean, that called it back in if the value is true

    finaldf = finaldf[finaldf.WO_Stat.str.contains('Complete', na=False)] #make df only contain complete orders
    #the above appears to work great as of 4.18

    #newcolumns = ['Days_Late', 'New_Days_Late', 'Status', 'Day', 'On_Time/Late', 'Cust_PO_#&_WO']
    #finaldf = finaldf.reindex(columns = newcolumns)
    finaldf = finaldf.assign(Days_Late = "", New_Days_Late="", Status="", Day="", On_Time_or_Late="", Cust_PO_WO="", On_Time_Units="", On_Time_Orders="")
    finaldf = finaldf[['column1,column2,Original_Due_Date,column3']]
    #finaldf['Completed_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Completed_Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date()
    #finaldf['Orginal_Due_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Original_Due_Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date()
    finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Original_Due_Date']>= 'Completed_Date'),'On_Time_Units'] = 'Order_Qty'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('currentweek.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    finaldf.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')    
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two date columns and validate if DateA is earlier than DateB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528084/compare-two-date-columns-and-validate-if-datea-is-earlier-than-dateb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does this mean?

```
finaldf['Original_Due_Date' >= 'Completed_Date'
```

It's grammatically incorrect, should be

```
finaldf['Original_Due_Date'] >= 'Completed_Date'
```

Even then, you are comparing `Timestamp` (`finaldf['Original_Due_Date']`) to `str` (`'Completed_Date'`), hence the error. I guess what you meant is:

```
finaldf['Original_Due_Date'] >= finaldf['Completed_Date']
```

PS: Edit for updated questions:

```
flags = (finaldf['Original_Due_Date'] >= finaldf['Completed_Date'])

finaldf.loc[flags, 'On_Time_Units'] = finaldf.loc[flags, 'Order_Qty']
```

That's it, I ain't answer no more question.

```
finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Original_Due_Date']>= finaldf['Completed_Date']),'On_Time_Units'] = finaldf.Order_Qty
```

This also works :)

Comment: thank you !!! but I have one more questions for now on that - because the whole reason is to have the condition pass in the Order_Qty, and you see I edited the code to df[columnname], but before 'order_qty' just passed it in as a sttring? If you want I can put in another question?

Comment: thank you @Quang Hoang , I found another way, I should have waited to ask you I am so sorry, but thank you so much I have learned a lot working with you on this project!

Comment: finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Original_Due_Date']>= finaldf['Completed_Date']),'On_Time_Units'] = finaldf.Order_Qty